# Recognized devices system in php

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, social-networking

Im making a social network and im trying to implement this feature where if the user is logged in from a different machine it will ask him to type in the password or identify his friends like in facebook.
I can do this using IP checks but that would be stupid if if the user had dynamic ip adress, then another option is cookies but that would also be stupid for many reasons - one being that its client side.

So then, i think mac address will be the thing to use, but i have no idea how to grab the mac address using php or javascript.
I think if this is possible, then it will be via js because it is client side
So any suggestions?

Comment: Google does something similar; but it compares the _region_ of your dynamic/static IP with past-used regions, and complains if you switched regions too fast.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it 'stupid' to use client-side information for authentication, that's where you'll be getting the username and password from and you're likely trusting that already

There is no way to grab the user's MAC address unless you're on the same network and the network allows such a lookup using ARP

You'll likely have to use cookies for this, and just make sure not to clear them if a particular browser is 'trusted'. If you think users are likely to share cookies with each other along with their username and password you could encode some other browser specific fields (exact UA header?) into the cookie to add more data you can use to decide if the client is trusted

Comment: I meant it will be stupid to use cookies for this recognized devices purpose because what if the cookie is deleted from his home pc and then he has to identify he clears cookies or it expires. Which would be annoying.

Comment: That's what happens with Facebook and Google if you clear all cookies; if you have login approvals enabled you have to re-verify the device

Comment: @lgy, never happened to me bro.
I clear bookies a lot and it never asked me to re-verify the device

Comment: It depends on the security options you have, i explicitly require confirmation for new devices; the auto-triggered protection of Google and Facebook may be less strict to avoid people having login problems

Answer (score 0):

That's more a comment than an answer:

> Im making a social network and im trying to implement this feature where if the user is logged in from a different machine it will ask him to type in the password or identify his friends like in facebook.

I'm not the author of that feature from facebook, so I don't have the specification of that feature at hand. If you would be so kind and add the specification of the feature you ask a question about to your question, it's probably possible to answer your question profoundly.

Comment: I'd like to implement a feature where I can identify a device without having to rely on cookies, can I guess?

Comment: Which identification services are offered by the devices you want to identify? You access the device via HTTP, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution
I can use this api http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php And grab the location of my users and if it changes ask them to verify device.